# how to call android.intent.action.SEND from href

Tags: share, intentfilter

i want to call the android.intent.action.SEND intent from html (test)
i have found several ways of call an intent on the internet, but i still haven't found the code to call the share intent from a web link...

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer is you can't.

After a bit of googling the only link that made sense to me was: intent://www.google.com/#Intent;scheme=http;action=android.intent.action.SEND;end

But it android doesn't pick it up. At least not on my device...

Comment: There is a  public discussion on this: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-web-intents/